# How to avoid React Hooks inside loops and conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following problem: I am using an Use Effect Hook to update my taskList when I open my WebApp. So I have to lists a list with task which has the attribute recurring tasks (recuringTaskManager.lastWeeklyReset) and a list which can have attributes with recurring and without (taskList). So my goal is to update taskList with the other one when a special condition occur (if differenceInDays....). so I want to delete some tasks in Taskslist therefore the filter function and add them again so that a special attribute can get refreshed. I found out that using hooks in conditions and loops is always bad but I don't know how I could code it without loops and conditions.

Maybe you know

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isInitialized) return
    if (differenceInDays(new Date("July 28, 2022 00:00:00"), state.recuringTaskManager.lastWeeklyReset) >= 7) {
      for (let task of state.recuringTaskManager.recuringTaskListWeekly) {
        const {id} = task
        setState({...state, taskList: state.taskList.filter((task: Task) => task.id !== id)})
state.recuringTaskManager.recuringTaskListWeekly)
      }

      setState({...state, taskList: [...state.recuringTaskManager.recuringTaskListWeekly, ...state.taskList]})
    }
  }, [isInitialized])
```

Comment: It's not bad, It's impossible to use hooks inside of functions. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. And create a function outside of the useEffect and call that function inside useEffect to keep the code clean and make it easier to debug.

Comment: This isn't actually a case of using a hook inside a function, but rather repeatedly setting state in a loop, each one of which will trigger a new render. Instead, compose your new state object assigned to a separate variable, and then call `setState` once with that composed object

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to avoid that is to set a variable and increment it in the loop and then set the state outside the loop or I think for your case you can just do this in one line

```
setState({...state, taskList: state.taskList.filter(({id}) => !state.recuringTaskManager.recuringTaskListWeekly.some(({id: id2}) => id === id2))})
```

The some method return true if one of the item of the array met the condition, if not it returns false